# TypeORM commands return nothing

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs, typeorm, ts-node

I have a Nest project with TypeORM. Few months ago, I setup my database, but I didn't test the database anymore (run migrations, seeding, drop schema, etc.).
Now, I'm trying to run any TypeORM command and nothing happens.

I tried to run TypeORM with this two:

```
ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js
```

```
node --require ts-node/register ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js
```

Nest: v7.4
Nest TypeORM: v7.1.5
TypeORM: v0.2.24 (but CLI returns v6.14.11)

Oh, almost forgot, I realized that my Node was outdated, in v13, then I updated to the v14, so maybe it brokes some package or build, I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Some points that might help:

- TypeORM operates on the generated JS code. Build the project first before running a migration or schema log command.
- There must be a ormconfig.js file being generated into the build output directory. Make sure the file is there.
- Check the glob patterns in the ormconfig file. I first made the mistake and defined the wildcards for Typescript files. But again, TypeORM CLI is working on the build output, so the glob patterns must target JS files. If I remember right, TypeORM schema:log command was telling me that there are no changes in my schema, but I knewthere were. And the problem was my faulty ormconfig file.

I have these scripts defined in my package.json and noticed that I explicitly provide the path to the ormconfig file compared to your command. Maybe you can try this:

```
"typeorm:cli": "ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register ./node_modules/typeorm/cli -f dist/src/database/config/ormconfig.js"
"migration:show": "npm run typeorm:cli -- migration:show",
"schema:log": "npm run build && npm run typeorm:cli -- schema:log",
```

Comment: Actually, I ran typeorm with `-f src/database/config/typeorm.config.ts` and it detects the file, but it gives me an error: `Error during migration show: MissingDriverError: Wrong driver: "undefined" given.`; and it says the same thing when I ran with the JS file on dist folder.

Comment: Also, I specify the config file, but with the option `--config`. Anyway, it didn't work in both ways.

Comment: Do you get this error, concerning the database driver? https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/4068

You can try some suggestions from there. If it doesn't help, do you have your repo public somewhere to have a look at? Or can you update your question and show your ormconfig file and also the part where you import the TypeOrmModule and provide the ormconfig for the module.

Comment: I had a second look at your comment. When you run the command with '-f src/database/config/typeorm.config.ts' then you provided the TypeScript file from the source directory. The config usually contains relative paths for the entities and migration files. TypeOrm CLI would interpret these paths relative to the TypeScript file then. But instead, TypeOrm must work on the generated JavaScript, i.e. your build output. So start the cli with '-f  yourBuildOutputDir/../typeorm.config.js'

Comment: I really appreciate your help, I was spending a lot of time on this, so I re-install the dependencies from scratch, because of what I said about deprecated Node version (and other reasons). I did this and in the end, it worked. However, I wish I could know the reason why it didn't work before. But thanks for trying to help me.

Comment: You're welcome, I could feel your pain, as I lost some time on this as well for my project :) Maybe it was just this: the dependency tree was broken due to some updates. I read before that for example the npm commands to remove or prune dependencies can lead to differend results compared to a clean install from scratch, as they cannot remove all of the non-needed transitive dependencies that were introduced by the dependency you want to remove.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is probably caused by [this bug](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/5949).

Solution is to downgrade Node or upgrade `pg` package.